# Посчитать кол-во элементов в каждом блоке

Tags: javascript, jquery

уже с ума схожу, не пойму как сделать следующее:
Есть несколько блоков и внутри каждого разное кол-во span. Как посчитать для каждого блока кол-во span и вывести число в соответствующем блоке.
Напишите, пожалуйста готовый ответ, если можно, очень нужно.

```html
<div data-index="1">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <p>И тут число</p>
</div>
<div data-index="2">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <p>И тут число</p>
</div>
<div data-index="3">
  <span></span>
  <p>И тут число</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('div[data-index]').each(function() {
  $(this).find('p').text($(this).find('span').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-index="1">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <p>И тут число</p>
</div>
<div data-index="2">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <p>И тут число</p>
</div>
<div data-index="3">
  <span></span>
  <p>И тут число</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Очень просто и на чистом JS.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[data-index]').forEach($div => {
  const spanCount = $div.querySelectorAll('span').length
  $div.querySelector('p').textContent = spanCount
})
```

```html
<div data-index="1">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <p>И тут число</p>
</div>
<div data-index="2">
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <p>И тут число</p>
</div>
<div data-index="3">
  <span></span>
  <p>И тут число</p>
</div>
```